# Do I need to create a migration in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

On Cocoa Realm, I changed a field for a class from this

```
public var person: Person {
    return linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "someProperty").first!
}
```

to this

```
public dynamic var person: Person!
```

Do I need a migration to update the scheme?

Comment: I would have thought so - the old definition doesn't store anything for `person` on the database, whereas the new definition does.

Comment: It seems like you have to. Best way to see is to try to launch the app with the new scheme though.